# How to create an Expression predicate from this?

Tags: c#, lambda, entity-framework-core, predicate

Basic question: How do I "build" a expression predicate based on the following example

```
e => e.Data.RootElement.GetProperty("pnt_name").GetString()
```

The context

The following statement is taken from https://www.npgsql.org/efcore/mapping/json.html?tabs=data-annotations%2Cjsondocument

```
var joes = context.Customers
    .Where(e => e.Customer.RootElement.GetProperty("Name").GetString() == "Joe")
    .ToList();
```

It explains how to use a JsonDocument mapping and not strongly typed Poco objects.

I am looking for a way to create Expression predicate with the .net Expression API ?
I am looking for a way to create a predicate that "looks" up properties on a JsonElement that resides in a Data column in a Postgresql db.
I would like to be able to get rows from ObjectSource there the JsonElement has property pnt_name and value ABC123. See the following example of a "compiled" version:

```
var names = context.ObjectSources
    .Where(e => e.Data.RootElement.GetProperty("pnt_name").GetString() == "ABC123")
    .ToList();
```

My datamodel looks like this:

```
  public class ObjectSource
  {

      [Key]
      public string ObjectSourceEId { get; set; }
      public string ObjectSourceIId { get; set; }
      public JsonDocument Data { get; set; }
      public int ObjectSourceEnvironment { get; set; }
      public string ObjectSourceCatalog { get; set; }
      public string ObjectSourceTable { get; set; }
      public string State { get; set; }
      public DateTime CreatedAd { get; set; }
      public DateTime UpdatedAt { get; set; }
  }
```

The Data field contains JSON data

```
[
   {"name" : "ABC123"},
   {"name" : "asd123"}
]
```

This is what I have tried

I am able to get Data property from ObjectSource like this:

```
var property = Expression.Property(parm, typeof(T).GetProperty("Data"));
```

parm being the ObjectSource and Data being the field on ObjectSource.

As I understand it I should be able to get the pnt_name like this:

```
e.Data.RootElement.GetProperty("pnt_name").GetString() == "ABC123")
```

Note that the pnt_name is NOT a property on Data, but a field in the JSON data that resides as a value on Data.

Just dont know how to "build" the predicate? How to i build up the above predicate in a dynamic fashion?

Here is a picture of the JSON structure and data in the column Data based on the entity ObjectSource. The values are different from the above but it should not matter.
[image]

Comment: An expression to do what? Your question is very unclear and doesn't show what you have tried.

Comment: @DavidG I have updated the question - maybe it helped?

Comment: Where is the "pnt_name" property coming from? The "event"  is the only property name provided in the sample JSON. Also, the sample JSON is not valid. It is missing the `[` and `]` around the elements in the "event" array.

Comment: @DamienD "pnt_name" is a field in the json object that is in located in "data".

Comment: I have corrected the json example

Comment: Your question is super confusing because none of your example data matches what your query is supposed to be doing. What is `e.ObjectSource` for example? Please give a [mre]

Comment: @DavidG You are absolutely right. I just corrected the example you reffered to. Sry

Comment: And just corrected it a fourth time

Comment: But that was just one example. Now your query references `pnt_name` but your example data doesn't contain that property. I'm not going to ask you again to correct it, good luck finding an answer.

Comment: pnt_name is a field in the Json object and not a property on Data. But the Data property holds json structure and data including the field pnt_name.

Comment: Which ORM do you use?

Comment: Entity Framework

Comment: I cannot understand purpose of this expression tree building. How do you plan to use it? I can help here, i can build ANY Expression Tree.

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv thanks..
I am not sure how to explain it... I think you should omit the RootElement. So like this: e => e.Data.GetProperty("pnt_name").GetString() == "ABC123" 
The Data holds JsON value.  Data is of type JsonElement. GetProperty is the method that will get JSON fields from json string. 

Does that help?

Comment: I can understand if you need the following function `public static IQueryable<T> FilterByJson(this IQueryable<T> query, Expression<Func<T, JsonDocument>> documentProp, string propName, string value)` - it is doable.

Comment: The MethodInfo (GetProperty) used for Expression Call is something like this: typeof(JsonElement).GetMethods(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public).Where(m => m.Name.ToString() == nameof(JsonElement.GetProperty)).FirstOrDefault();

The bindingflag is set to Instance. Therefore the Expression.Call() must take in an Expression instance. ???

Comment: You do not need any of those.

Comment: It is based on this :https://github.com/JeremyLikness/ExpressionGenerator/blob/master/ExpressionGenerator/JsonExpressionParser.cs
But yes, I would like to filter a list based on the predicates

Comment: I'll prepare solution in several minutes.

Comment: Crazy @SvyatoslavDanyliv THanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This simple extension method should allow to create such filters.

Usage sample:

```cs
var joes = context.Customers
    .FilterInJson(e => e.Customer.RootElement, "Name", "Joe")
    .ToList();
```

And realisation:

```cs
public static class JsonQueryableExtensions
{
    public static IQueryable<TEntity> FilterInJson<TEntity>(this IQueryable<TEntity> query,
        Expression<Func<TEntity, JsonElement>> elementProp, string propName, string value)
    {
        // Let the Compiler to do amount of work by himself
        Expression<Func<JsonElement, string, string, bool>> template = 
            (elementParam, propNameParam, valueParam) => elementParam.GetProperty(propNameParam).GetString() == valueParam;

        var replacements = new List<Expression>
        {
            elementProp.Body, 
            Expression.Constant(propName), 
            Expression.Constant(value),
        };

        // replacing template parameters
        var visitor = new ReplacingExpressionVisitor(template.Parameters, replacements);
        var predicateBody = visitor.Visit(template.Body);

        var predicate = Expression.Lambda<Func<TEntity, bool>>(predicateBody, elementProp.Parameters);

        return query.Where(predicate);
    }
}
```

Comment: It is what you need? Or for you better to create call to this method explicitly?

Comment: I just need to work it out, I will return later. Thanks for your input. Maybe you could join me in the chat: https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/255578/expression-predicate